# POSIX - problemas para escrever em arquivo usando open e write

Tags: c, posix

Sobre esse código abaixo, esta dando problema no write, porém se eu usar o creat sem as flags ele roda. 
O objetivo é copiar um arquivo, o arquivo que será copiado se chama 'teste.txt' e o que será criado 'novoteste.txt', mas se o novoteste.txt já estiver criado é para retornar uma mensagem de erro. Com o creat não da pra fazer sem gambiarra (até onde eu sei). Por isso estou tentando usar o open.

segue o código:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  /*-------criando o novo arquivo---------*/
  mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
  /*
  S_IRUSR
      read permission, owner
  S_IWUSR
      write permission, owner
  S_IRGRP
      read permission, group
  S_IROTH
      read permission, others
  */
  struct stat     statbuf;
  int arqEntrada, arqSaida, tamanho, tambloco;
  char *filename = "teste.txt";

  if( ( arqEntrada = open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK, mode) ) == -1) {
    printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ( stat(filename, &statbuf) == -1) {
    printf("Erro no stat!");
    exit(1);
  }
  tamanho = statbuf.st_size;
  tambloco = statbuf.st_blksize;

  char *filename2 = "novoteste.txt";

  if( ( arqSaida = open(filename2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, mode) ) == -1)  {
    printf("Erro ao criar novo arquivo!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  ssize_t bytes_read, bytes_written;
  char buf[tamanho];
  size_t nbytes;

  nbytes = sizeof(buf);

  if( ( bytes_read = read(arqEntrada, buf, nbytes) ) == -1) {
    printf("Erro no read!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if( ( bytes_written = write(arqSaida, buf, nbytes) ) == -1) {
    printf("Erro no write!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: //essas são as bibliotecas e desculpem pela má formatação, não posso mais editar.\n
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

Answer (score 0):

No momento de criar o arquivo cópia, é preciso informar a permissão de Read e Write neste novo arquivo cópia com a flag `O_RDWR`:

```
if( ( arqSaida = open(filename2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, mode) ) == -1)  {
  printf("Erro ao criar novo arquivo!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Dessa forma, o arquivo novo é criado (`O_CREAT` e `O_EXCL`) e tem permissão de escrever o conteúdo do arquivo original (`O_RDWR`).

Referencias sobre as oflags e modes podem ser vistas [neste codewiki](http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open)